# Как из txt файла (с помощью специальных символов) вытащить нужный мне фрагмент текста и сохранить его в списке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

```
import re

text = """

//А//Роман//А//
1.0
//А//Пётр//А//
12.25

//А//Иван Иванов//А//
1.256

//А//Саша and Маша//А// 
15.1 

"""

matches = re.findall(r'//А//([а-яА-Яеёa-z]+)//А//.+?(\d+)',text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

Вот такой должен получиться  список:

```
[('Роман', '1.0'), ('Пётр', '12.25'), ('Иван Иванов', '1.256'), ('Саша and Маша', '15.1') ]
```

Но в итоге у меня получается вот такой список:

```
[('Роман', '1'), ('Пётр', '12')]
```

Я понимаю, что мне нужно правильно написать регулярное выражения, но как я не пытался у меня не получается это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\d` это эквивалент `[0-9]`, т.е. только целые числа им описываются, поэтому нужно дробную часть также описывать:

```
matches = re.findall(r'//\w//([\w\s]+)//.+?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

Консоль:

```
[('Роман', '1.0'), ('Пётр', '12.25'), ('Иван Иванов', '1.256'), ('Саша and Маша', '15.1')]
```

Comment: Несколько улучшенная версия: `re.findall(r'//\w//([\w\s]+)//.+?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)', text, flags=re.DOTALL|re.U)` - понимает любые юникодные буквы и не ломается на целых числах... ;-)

Comment: спс, обновил регулярку

Comment: Спасибо большое  MaxU и  gil9red за помощь )))

Comment: @MaxU re.U тут ничего не делает (Python 3).

Comment: `\d` больше чем `[0-9]` покрывает: `re.findall(r'\d+', ''.join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode))))`

Comment: @jfs, а везде написано, что `\d Соответствует цифровому символу. Эквивалентно выражению [0-9]`. Интересно, что похоже `re.findall(r'\d+', ''.join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode)))` вывел числа из других кодировок и там не только арабские нашлись

Comment: @gil9red на входе у вас Unicode, так что забудьте о кодировках. `\d` здесь эквивалентен str.isdecimal